# Screen flashes when using rtl support in ionic 2

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developing a dual language app using `ionic 2`. Languages are English and Arabic. By startup, I'm using default language as English. when changing from English to Arabic the direction changes from `ltr` to `rtl`. But I have a form with inputs work fine at startup, after changing the language, when I click the form elements the screen starts to flash. Moving back from Arabic to English is also the same issue. Works fine only at startup. Any possible solution?

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { scrollAssist: true, autoFocusAssist : true})
```

when I turn scrollAssist to false no screen flashes found. But I need to focus on the input element when the keyboard is up.

```
 this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
                this.textDir = event.lang == 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
                if (event.lang == 'ar') {

                    platform.setDir('rtl', true);
                    platform.setDir('ltr', false);
                    this.menuSide = 'right';

                }
                else {
                    platform.setDir('ltr', true);
                    platform.setDir('rtl', false);
                    this.menuSide = 'left';
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just commented this line.

```
            //this.textDir = event.lang == 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
```